# How to Improve Django Tastypie web server performance

Tags: django-models, tastypie

I have a django web server with Tastypie API. The performance is extremely slow, and I am not sure where to look.

The problem can be abstracted this way. It simply has 3 tables.

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Table2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    table1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1)

class Table3(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
   table2 = models.ForeignKey(Table2)
```

Table1 has about 50 record. Table2 has about 400 record. Table3 has about 2000 record. MySQL is used.

It has 3 model resource:

```
class Table1Resource(ModelResource):
  class Meta(object):
    """Define options attached to model."""
    queryset = models.Table1.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'table1'

class Table2Resource(ModelResource):
  class Meta(object):
    """Define options attached to model."""
    queryset = models.Table2.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'table2'

class Table3Resource(ModelResource):
  class Meta(object):
    """Define options attached to model."""
    queryset = models.Table3.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'table3'
```

The front-end uses ajax to call 3 web service APIsto retrieve all data in database. My machine has very good configuration, such as 16 GB memory. But, it takes about 40 seconds to load all data. Too slow. It's obvious something is not right.

I tried some Django data model function to improve performance

1) Django queryset. I notice the API retrieve all table objects if there is foreign key. Table3Resource access is extremely slow. In my case, I just want data in 1 table, not interested in inner join result from another table. For example, it uses models.Table3.objects.all().

I tried models.LabSpace.objects.select_relate(). No help at all.

2) For such small amount of data with such low performance, I am not even thinking Tastypie API cache technique yet. I feel somewhere is obviously wrong.

Basically, I am not sure if it is Django or Tastypie issue. Where should I look?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the Resource `ForeignKey` field. Default is `False` I believe, so you just have to do this:

```
class Table2Resource(ModelResource):
    table1 = fields.ToOneField(Table1Resource)

    class Meta(object):
        """Define options attached to model."""
        queryset = models.Table2.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'table2'

 # etc ...
```

If not you can try to explicitly set it like so:

```
table1 = fields.ToOneField(Table1Resource, 'table1', full=False)
```

Comment: Thanks it does help. I do have   table1 = fields.ForeignKey(Table1Resource, 'table1', full=True). Why it make such big difference?

Comment: When you specify `full=True` it fetches all the related objects. When set to false it only gives you the resource URL. If that resolved your problem, please accept the answer.